# Solving Generalized Heat Equation by separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the following problem
\begin{align*}
    u_{t}-\frac{v}{2}\cdot u_{xx}+\frac{v}{2}\cdot x^2 \cdot u(x)&=0 \\
    u(x,0)&=f(x)
\end{align*}
Where $f(x)=y_1(x)+0.2y_4(x)+0.01y_6(x)$.
[image]
$y_n$ are the Eigenfunctions that defined as $y_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)$

By separation of we assume $$u(x,t)=X(x)T(x)$$

I have found that the general solution of $T$ is
$$T(x)=c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$$
and the general solution of $X$ is
$$X_n(x)=\exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)$$

So the general solution to our initial problem is
$$u_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x) c_1e^{-\lambda v t}$$

Using the I.C we got $$u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \exp\left(\displaystyle{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right)H_n(x)=f(x)$$
How can I write the result in Fourier series form?

Comment: You need to solve for the coefficients $A_n$ to finish the calculation. You need to use the orthogonality of Hermite polynomials. Assuming your calculations are correct, this problem is similar to Fourier series in that you have developed an expansion in terms of orthogonal functions, but the solution isn't a Fourier series.

Comment: @kevinkayaks is it possible to help me with this? Because I am a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish your solution, you need to solve the equation
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n y_n(x) = y_1(x) + \frac{1}{5}y_4(x) + \frac{1}{100} y_6(x) $$ for the $A_n$.
To do this, you need to use the orthogonality property of hermite polynomials:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_m(x) H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi}n! \delta_{nm}.$$ Note we can rewrite this as $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_m(x) y_n(x) dx = \sqrt{2\pi}n! \delta_{nm}.$$
So we multiply the first equation by $H_m(x)$ and integrate over $x$.
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \sqrt{2\pi}n! \delta_{nm} = \sqrt{2\pi}1! \delta_{1m} + \frac{1}{5}\sqrt{2\pi}4! \delta_{4m}+ \frac{1}{100}\sqrt{2\pi}6! \delta_{6m} .$$
Can you take it from here? You just need to get $A_n$ for each $n=1,2,\dots,$

Comment: note I don't know which normalization convention of Hermite polynomials you're using, so this might be off by some factors. Anyway this hopefully shows you how to use the orthogonality property of your eigenfunctions to find the coefficients.

Comment: I have updated my question with the particular $f(x)$

Comment: Doesn't matter - just determine your orthogonality relation and use it. This is exactly the same as you would for a Fourier series, Bessel functions, or any other orthogonal set of functions which show up in these types of problems.